# SetOutputStream works with System.out but not with PrintStream

Tags: java, javafx, outputstream, printstream

Using JavaFX I am trying to redirect Jsch session.SetOutputStream to a TextArea in a form of a PrintStream. PrintStream works as excepted except for the session output.

TextArea PrintStream setup:

```
ConsoleClass console = new ConsoleClass(textArea);
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(console, true);
System.setOut(ps);

public class ConsoleClass extends OutputStream {

    private TextArea output;

    public ConsoleClass(TextArea ta) {
        this.output = ta;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(int i) throws IOException {
        output.appendText(String.valueOf((char) i));
    }
    @Override
    public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
        output.appendText(String.valueOf(b);
    }

}
```

Now I pass this ps (PrintStream) to the Jsch class. and I set the OutputStream as follow:

```
session.SetOutputStream(ps) //Nothing gets displayed
```

Note:

```
The ps still displays anything within the jsch class but not within its session.
```

To see what goes on in the session I have to

```
remove System.setOut(ps);
add session.SetOutputStream(System.out)
The same behavior applies to the channel.SetOutputStream
```

jsch:

```
jsch jsch = new Jsch();
Session session=jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
session.setPassword(passed);
session.connect(30000);
session.SetOutputStream(ps); // nothing gets displayed
//but when I set it to System.out it shows everything
session.SetOutputStream(System.out) // console shows the commands
if (session.isConnected()){
System.out.println(session.getHost() + "Session is Established");
//this shows in the TextArea
}
Channel channel=session.openChannel("shell");
System.out.println("Testing testing"); //shows in the TextArea

channel.disconnect();
System.out.println ("channel Status" + channel.getExitStatus); 
//shows in the TextArea
```

what am I missing? 
as you can see I am able to append System.out to the TextArea and I am having only the issue with session or channel .setOutputStream(ps)

```
.setOutputStream only shows what goes on in the session/channel 
when it's directed to System.out
```

Comment: Have you implemented the `write(byte b[])`?

Comment: Your implementation of `write(int)` is wrong. The `int` is the value of a **byte** of output, not a character. If your session sends out UTF-8 information, it will be sending two separate bytes for anything that is not ASCII. Also, how is your text area going to support control characters?

Comment: @Immueggpain it shouldn't be necessary, as `write(byte b[])` is implemented at the base class as several consecutive calls to `write(int)`.

Comment: Immueggpain, I haven't done byte b[ ] can you give me an example of how to modify my code above?

Comment: @RealSkeptic you are right... it shouldn't be the problem here

Comment: Anyway, from the sparse documentation on the Internet, `session.setOutputStream` doesn't do anything. You're supposed to set the output stream on the channel.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I tried both, nothing is getting displayed to the PrintStream.

Comment: So perhaps you should debug it and see what byte values are actually passed to it. They could be values that you don't expect.

Comment: What is `System.setOut(ps);` for? Also if `session.SetOutputStream(System.out)` works but `session.SetOutputStream(ps)` doesn't, the problem is likely to be located in your UI codes.

Comment: System.setOut(ps) --> to set System.out to printstream. I have tried the byte   [] b and still not working. any thoughts on what to do next?

Comment: How did you get the `textArea`? Also is `appendText` called within UI thread? I don't know if it's necessary but it's generally recommended.

Comment: updated the question with the jsch code snippet.

Comment: How about wrap `output.appendText(String.valueOf(b);` inside `Platform.runLater`? Does it work?

Comment: nothing happens, it's still not printing...

Comment: do I need to consider StandardCharsets.UTF_8? if so how can i integrate it?

Comment: use `new String(bytes, charset)`